# Is there a way generate AnyCPU DLL if one of my references is platform dependent?

Tags: c#, .net

My DLL has always been built as AnyCPU with all references being AnyCPU DLLs. Recently a third-party vendor has stopped supplying an AnyCPU dll that is referenced by my Library and started supplying two platform-specific DLLs: a 32-bit & 64-bit DLL. Is there a way/trick I can use to still produce my AnyCPU DLL so I don't affect my customers?

Comment: Well, sure, he just made it your job to deploy the correct one.

Comment: @HansPassant: deploy a DLL from a DLL? Hm...

Comment: nope. sorry. you could do dynamic loading but that would be a pain in the butt.

Comment: Are the two dll's .NET assemblies or are they native assemblies?

Comment: @ScottChamberlain .NET assemblies but who knows what they might be doing in them...

Comment: @DanielA.White -- that's a possibility... Ugly, I know...